# Convert Date (timestamp) field to day in hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am writing a system which will call database using hibernate framework. Database table has date time value but for all my use case I want day only. So I want to convert date field to day in select, group by and sort. What is recommended way or doing it?
I am using hibernate criteria and not running raw SQL query in hibernate.

I tried using:

`sqlProjection/sqlGroupProjection(sqlGroupProjection("to_char(EVENT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as day", "to_char(EVENT_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')",..,..)  but then I don't know how can I modify in Criteria.Order.`

Is there any way I can specify in model file itself to always convert date field to day. If not then how can trim date to day in criteria.Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define @Formula annotation and move your day claculation logic there. Then you can use the field in your queries.

See how to use formulas [here](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and) and [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation)